# Designing a probability question with two unknowns but a unique solution

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to design a probability problem with two unknowns, one equality, and a unique solution. My first attempt:

> Trillian has $n$ mice, of which $w$ are white. She chooses four at random. The probability that two are white is equal to the probability none are white.

As [demonstrated elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655204/ratios-of-binomial-coefficients), the non-trivial solutions satisfy the polynomial

$$(2n-2w-5)^2-6(2w-1)^2=-5$$

This is Pell's equation, and it has an infinite number of integer solutions:

$$(n,w) \in \{ (8,2), (15,4), (53,15), \ldots \}$$

Alas. This problem doesn't work for my project.

But can we design a probability question with a similar feel (two unknowns and one equality) that has a unique solution?

Comment: I'd like to tag this 'problem design' but the tag doesn't exist

Comment: thanks for thinking of a good tag. Done.